# How to make Angular keep two fields in sync?

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning Angular.  As an exercise, I am converting an existing application that uses jQuery to use Angular.

On my page, I have two inputs.  One is a combobox; the other is a text input.

When the user changes the selection in the combobox, the text input is populated with the text of the user's selection, unless the user selects an entry called "Custom" in the combobox.  When the user selects "Custom", the text input is cleared and the focus automatically moves to the text input for the user to key in a custom value.

Whenever the user manually moves the focus to the text input and keys in something, the value of the combobox automatically changes to "Custom".

What is the appropriate way to go about doing this in Angular?

I suppose that if I had two identical text inputs, I could just ng-bind them to the same model, but this is different.  I'm guessing that I must capture events and manually update the model, but I'd like to hear from more experienced folks.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap some logic inside a `$watch` in your controller or maybe prefer directives like `ng-click` and `ng-change`.

I think Nikos Paraskevopoulos' answer was good one but it didn't really answer to your question about focusing/clearing your inputs.

Here's one way I might accomplish this. First the HTML template.

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="vm.selected.value"
       ng-change="vm.inputChanged()"
       focus-when-empty>

<select ng-model="vm.selected.option" 
        ng-change="vm.selectionChanged()"
        ng-options="option for option in vm.options">
</select>
```

That's pretty clear. There's separate model for text `input` and `selection`, some options to choose from and `ng-change` handler for both. Controller could be something like

```
app.controller('MainController', function() {
  var vm = this;

  // your options to select from
  vm.options = ['custom','one','two','three'];

  // current text input value and dropdown selection
  vm.selected = {
    value: null,
    option: null
  };

  // handle text input
  vm.inputChanged = function() {
    var index = vm.options.indexOf(vm.selected.value);
    vm.selected.option = index > 0 ? vm.options[index] : vm.options[0];
  };

  // handle dropdown
  vm.selectionChanged = function() {
    var index = vm.options.indexOf(vm.selected.option);
    vm.selected.value = index > 0 ? vm.selected.option : null;
  };
});
```

Focusing on text input, when "custom" was selected, was little trickier so it's handled via simple `focus-when-empty` directive.

```
app.directive('focusWhenEmpty', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      // if there is no model, focus on element
      scope.$watch('ngModel', function(value) {
        if (!value) {
          element[0].focus();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And as a added bonus, if you type in any of the values in your options, selection is then updated accordingly (so it's not "custom" anymore).

---

Here's the related plunker, hope it helps! http://plnkr.co/edit/uJeV5L

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Nice excercise :)

A traditional solution is with a watch and using the change event on the input:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this, changeIsInternal = false;

    this.selection = null;
    this.options = [
        'custom',
        'alpha',
        'beta'
    ];
    this.custom = null;

    this.customChanged = function() {
        if( this.selection !== 'custom' ) {
            this.selection = 'custom';
            changeIsInternal = true;
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch(
        function() {
            return self.selection;
        },
        function(newval, oldval) {
            if( newval !== oldval ) { // needed to skip initialization
                if( changeIsInternal ) {
                    changeIsInternal = false;
                }
                else {
                    if( newval !== 'custom' ) {
                        self.custom = newval;
                    }
                    else {
                        self.custom = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

And its relevant HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
    <select ng-model="ctrl.selection" ng-options="o for o in ctrl.options"></select>
    <br/>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.custom" ng-change="ctrl.customChanged()" focus-when="ctrl.selection === 'custom'" />
    <br/>
    <pre><code>{{ ctrl | json }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Another solution is with custom object properties; this uses *NO WATCHES* and I believe is *Angular 2 friendly*:

```
app.controller('Ctrl2', (function() {
    function Ctrl2() {
        this._selection = null;
        this.options = [
            'custom',
            'alpha',
            'beta'
        ];
        this._custom = null;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(Ctrl2.prototype, 'selection', {
        get: function() { return this._selection; },
        set: function(value) {
            if( value !== 'custom' ) {
                this._custom = value;
            }
            else {
                this._custom = '';
            }
            this._selection = value;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(Ctrl2.prototype, 'custom', {
        get: function() { return this._custom; },
        set: function(value) {
            this._selection = 'custom';
            this._custom = value;
        }
    });

    return Ctrl2;
})());
```

The HTML is the same, omitting the `ng-change` part.

(**EDIT: Setting focus...**)
In both cases I suggest the following directive for setting the focus:

```
app.directive('focusWhen', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                $parse(attrs.focusWhen),
                function(newval, oldval) {
                    if( newval && newval !== oldval ) {
                        elem[0].focus();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

The `if( newval !== oldval )` part is to prevent focus stealing if the inital value of `selection` is `"custom"`.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6dn55t5w/1/

(**EDIT Comments...**)
The answer from Mikko Viitala interestingly shows the `ng-change` version for listening to changes of the select box. This is probably better suited for this question (instead of using the watch) as the OP states: "When the user changes the selection in the combobox". Use a watch when the model may also be changed programmatically, as the change event will not be fired in that case. Use `ng-change` when it is guaranteed that only the UI can change a value.

I still find the `Object.defineProperty` version interesting, as it can handle both UI and programmatic changes without watches.

Comment: I'm sorry to have given a negative vote ... not just because you skipped the part of the "focus" but especially for that useless variable changeIsInternal.

Comment: Trully, I forgot the focus point (I am troubled about the best solution to this), but the variable *IS* necessary if you *go for a watch* to avoid circles - that is why I suggest the second solution. Unless of course you care to answer *with a watch* without the (ugly) variable.